# Fastest algorithm for finding first k elements in ordered cross sums of two sorted arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have two sorted arrays `x[]` and `y[]` of floats. The array sizes are `n` and `m` respectively.

I need to find the ordered `k`-th, `k` << `min(m, n)`, element in the array of cross sums, i.e. `s = {x[0] + y[0], x[0] + y[1], ..., x[0] + y[m-1], x[1] + y[0], x[1] + y[1], ..., x[1] + y[m-1], ..., x[n-1] + y[0], x[n-1] + y[1], ..., x[n-1] + y[m-1]}`.

My current method is more or less to concatenate the arrays of

`{x[0] + y[0], x[0] + y[1], ..., x[0] + y[m-1]}`,

`{x[1] + y[0], x[1] + y[1], ..., x[1] + y[m-1]}`,

...

`{x[k-1] + y[0], x[k-1] + y[1], ..., x[k-1] + y[m-1]}`,

`{y[0] + x[0], y[0] + x[1], ..., y[0] + x[n-1]}`,

`{y[1] + x[0], y[1] + x[1], ..., y[1] + x[n-1]}`,

...

`{y[k-1] + x[0], y[k-1] + x[1], ..., y[k-1] + x[n-1]}`,

and then select the `k`-th element.

My guess is that the problem should've had some significance in convolution-related algorithms. What's the fastest way to achieve it?

Comment: @Jetunsaure This is not true.

Comment: x[i] = 7*i, y[j] = 5*j. The sorted table looks like that `[((0,0),0),((0,1),5),((1,0),7),((0,2),10),((1,1),12),((2,0),14),((0,3),15),((1,2),17),((2,1),19),((0,4),20),((3,0),21),((1,3),22),((2,2),24),((0,5),25),((3,1),26),((1,4),27),((4,0),28),((2,3),29),((0,6),30),((3,2),31),((1,5),32),((4,1),33),((2,4),34),((0,7),35),((5,0),35),...`

Comment: @Jetunsaure I'm not sure what your method is then. Can you mark the first 5 elements, showing which elements you examine and how you change current row and current column? How many elements do you need to examine in total?

Comment: @Jetunsaure Could you be so kind to provide some code like in Python or C++?

Comment: @Jetunsaure You said earlier "the next marked element will always be to the right of the last marked element in a given row or..." but now it is clear that it will be to the right of the last marked element in some row. You need to check all the rows being explored, and possibly open a new one. And then at every step check at least all the rows you checked at the previous step.

Comment: @Jetunsaure This is basically a multi-way merge, but it is nigh impossible to understand that from your initial description.

Comment: Do you want the k'th smallest sum, or the k'th sum in the unsorted sum table you've listed above?

Comment: @DillonDavis k-th element in the sorted array of the cross sums

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a python implementation of the algorithm @Jetunsaure proposed. It does the minimal amount of addition necessary to compute the final result:

```py
def kth_smallest_sum(x, y, k):
    row = min_row = 0
    max_row = len(x)
    max_col = len(y)
    indexes = [0] * max_row
    for _ in range(k):
        msum = None
        for r in range(min_row, min(row+2, max_row)):
            c = indexes[r]
            tsum = x[r] + y[c]
            if msum is None or tsum < msum:
                minr, msum = r, tsum
        ksum = msum
        if indexes[minr] == max_col - 1:
            min_row += 1
        else:
            indexes[minr] += 1
        row = max(row, minr)
    return ksum
```

Sample usage:

```
kth_smallest_sum([i * 7 for i in range(10)], [i * 5 for i in range(10)], 8)
```

Output:

```
17
```

**Update**

I modified the original code to support `k` values greater than `min(len(x), len(y)` (see above). I then ran performance testing on this and @DillonDavis solution, using x, y data pf lengths 100, 100; 10, 1000; and 1000, 10 with `k` ranging from 1 to 8192 in powers of 2. The testing code was this:

```
random.seed('kth')
for N, M in [(10, 1000), (100, 100), (1000, 10)]:
    x = sorted(random.sample(range(N*5), N))
    y = sorted(random.sample(range(M*5), M))
    
    out = perfplot.bench(
        setup=lambda n:n,
        kernels = [lambda n: find_kth_smallest(x, y, n), lambda n:kth_smallest_sum(x, y, n)],
        n_range = [2**x for x in range(13)],
        labels = ['heap', 'list']
    )
    out.save(f'{N}x{M}.png')
```

The results were as follows. As can be seen the heap performance is fairly constant (consistent with `O(k log k)`) where the list performance is affected by the size of the lists (consistent with `O(k min(N,M))`

**100x100**:
[image]

**10x1000**:
[image]

**1000x10**:
[image]

Comment: Thanks!  `sums = defaultdict(float)` is irrelevant there?

Comment: I don't believe this code works. It returns an incorrect sum for `xs = [6, 34, 11, 98, 52, 34, 13, 4, 48, 68, 71, 42]; `ys = [43, 6, 20, 17, 43, 71, 42, 89, 31, 20, 0, 55]`, and even returns different results if you swap xs/ys.

Comment: @DillonDavis input arrays are sorted

Comment: Ah, right.  My mistake!

Comment: @user2961927 sorry, yes, that's an oops. I was experimenting with caching sum results - but found it was slower than just doing them all - and forgot to remove it. I'll edit...

Answer (score 5):

I have an alternative implementation of nearly the same algorithm at the accepted answer, just slightly faster and robust to larger values of k. The idea is to use a min-heap to track the smallest values on each row as they are encountered, and explore those rows lazily until the kth value is discovered. This gives the algorithm a `O(k log k)` runtime, vs `O(k^2)` of the straight list iteration approach.

```py
from heapq import heappop, heappush

def find_kth_smallest(rows, cols, k):
    max_row = row = col = 0
    heap = [(rows[row] + cols[col], row, col)]
    
    for _ in range(k):
        value, row, col = heappop(heap)
        if col + 1 < len(cols):
            heappush(heap, (rows[row] + cols[col+1], row, col+1))
        if row + 1 < len(rows) and row == max_row:
            max_row += 1
            heappush(heap, (rows[row+1] + cols[0], row+1, 0))
    
    return value
```

This will gracefully handle valid inputs up to `k = n * m - 1`, though its less efficient to do so for large `k`.

I also want to weigh in on your comment:

> My guess is that the problem should've had some significance in convolution-related algorithms.

I see the connection, however what you're asking for is related to the cartesian product of the two series, whereas a convolution would involve the cauchy product of the two.

Even so, you could still represent your series as a polynomial, with some benefit:

```
P(x) = (x^a[0] + x^a[1] + ... + x^a[n]) * (x^b[0] + x^b[1] + ... + x^b[m])
```

The product would then give give you polynomial with the order of each term being the pair sum and the coefficient being a count. You could of course multiply these in `O(a[n] * b[m] log (a[n] * b[m]))` time using the FFT, but that would be terrible.

You could instead get the sum of the coefficients by evaluating this polynomial as `x=1` and simplify, prior to taking the product between the two polynomials. Initially this would equal `len(a) * sum(b) + len(b) * sum(a)` (the sum of all pairs of elements). However, you could then truncate the `a` and/or `b` series at `n'` and `m'`, evaluate the new polynomials at `x=1`, and get a new sum. This sum will be a lower bound for the number of sums smaller than `a[n'] + b[m']`.

You could binary search in this fashion for a close approximation for your target sum for a given `k`, but this is where we are stuck- I'm not quite sure how to get the exact value from here. There's ways using primitive roots of unity to count the exact counts of multiples of each sum (e.g. how many pair sums are a multiply of `7`, counting duplicates?), however this isn't feasible to repeat for all possible sums, and it doesn't otherwise help us get the exact sum of counts less than some value.